# Symfony2 or Doctrine2 isn't unserializing values

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I serialize some values when I send to DB, now I need to unserialize them in order to iterate over them. In my entity I have this:

```
public function getValuesText() {
    return $this->values_text;
}
```

and then in the template I show as:

```
{{ element.getValuesText }}
```

But I get this raw result:

```
a:3:{i:1;s:7:"Value 1";i:2;s:7:"Value 2";i:3;s:7:"Value 3";}
```

And I don't know how to iterate over it to get key, values, what is failing?

**UPDATE: Include mapping information**

Here is:

```
<?php

namespace ProductBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use ProductBundle\DBAL\Types\StatusType;
use ProductBundle\DBAL\Types\FieldType;
use Fresh\Bundle\DoctrineEnumBundle\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_detail")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class ProductDetail {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductDetail")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $label;

    /**
     * @var string $field_type
     * @DoctrineAssert\Enum(entity="ProductBundle\DBAL\Types\FieldType")
     * @ORM\Column(name="field_type", type="FieldType", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $field_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="values_text", type="array")
     */
    protected $values_text;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $measure_unit;

    /**
     * @var string $status
     * @DoctrineAssert\Enum(entity="ProductBundle\DBAL\Types\StatusType")
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="StatusType", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $modified;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CategoryBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="pd_category", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_detail_has_category",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="detail", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\DetailGroup", inversedBy="productDetail", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="detail_group_has_product_detail",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="detail", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="kgroup", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $detail_group;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="to_product", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $to_product;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->detail_group = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->category = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setParent(ProductDetail $parent = null) {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setLabel($label) {
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    public function getLabel() {
        return $this->label;
    }

    public function setFieldType($field_type) {
        $this->field_type = $field_type;
    }

    public function getFieldType() {
        return $this->field_type;
    }

    public function setValuesText($values_text) {
        $this->values_text = $values_text;
    }

    public function getValuesText() {
        return $this->values_text;
    }

    public function setMeasureUnit($measure_unit) {
        $this->measure_unit = $measure_unit;
    }

    public function getMeasureUnit() {
        return $this->measure_unit;
    }

    public function setStatus($status) {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setCreated($param) {
        $this->created = $param;
        return true;
    }

    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function setModified($param) {
        $this->modified = $param;
        return true;
    }

    public function getModified() {
        return $this->modified;
    }

    public function setCategory(\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category $category) {
        $this->category[] = $category;
    }

    public function getCategory() {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setDetailGroup(\ProductBundle\Entity\DetailGroup $detailGroup) {
        $this->detail_group[] = $detailGroup;
    }

    public function getDetailGroup() {
        return $this->detail_group;
    }

    public function getDeletedAt() {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt) {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;
    }

    public function setToProduct($to_product) {
        $this->to_product = $to_product;
    }

    public function getToProduct() {
        return $this->to_product;
    }

}
```

Comment: include your mapping information (annotation/yml/xml) for the entity you're trying to fetch in the question please.

Comment: @nifr done, added to main post

Comment: how are you fetching the entity from the repository? normally the property should be unserialized during this process. Did you clear your cache and update the database schema to the latest version before? :)

Comment: can you try mapping to `json_array` instead of `array` - clear cache, update your schema, recreate your database / reload your fixtures and see if the problem persists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after read and check my code I realize where the problem was:

- Doctrine DBAL takes care for serialize/unserialize by using `type="array"` [check here for more info](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types)
- I made a mistake when I insert values since I was doing a unwanted `serialize` since as I said before Doctrine take care of this. See below:

Incorrect:

```
$entity->setValuesText(serialize($form->get('values_text')->getData()));
```

Correct:

```
$entity->setValuesText($form->get('values_text')->getData());
```

That's all, hope is helpful for someone else

Answer (score -1):

Doctrine 2 DBAL ArrayType doesn't check for an array and serialize every type of parameter.

Control your database, that value should be a serialized string starting with `s:`

Ref: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/ArrayType.php

Comment: And how I do handle with this problem? And yes in my DB all the serialized values has `s:`

Comment: With a script get all these serialized value, unserialize them two times, first time from `s:` to `a:`, second time from `a:` to array and then store again using Doctrine